# Django 4.2 , GenericIPAddress and CIDR

Tags: python, django

Im updating a project from:

```
Python 3.9 + Postgres 13 + Django 4.0.6 + psycopg2
```

TO

```
Python 3.11 + Postgresql 15 + Django 4.2 + psycopg3
```

I have a big problem with GenericIPFields.
It seems that it doesn't support cidr anymore.

When I try to save an ORM with a cidr, I get:

```
ValueError: '10.255.96.48/28' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

I need that INET FIELD on DB with cidr to make queryes like:

```
Subnet.objects.filter().extra(where = [ "cidr::inet >>= inet '"+self.ip_address+"'" ])
```

and other cidr related queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: '10.0.0.0/24' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389019/valueerror-10-0-0-0-24-does-not-appear-to-be-an-ipv4-or-ipv6-network)

Comment: Unfortunally not because Im using a DB Model of Django that user ip_address inside to validate values

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, the problem is Psycopg3 that try some validation on fields before DB insert.

Unfortunally it seems that there is a problem with new ip_address library when it tries to check if string is an ip_address or an ip_network.

You have 2 Solution:

1. Put a fix in the library itself.

Open python/ipaddress.py on your environment dir.
Locate

```
def ip_address(address):
```

Replace:

```
try:
    return IPv4Address(address)
```

with:

```
try:
        if (type(address) == bytes and b"/" in address) or ("/" in address):
            return IPv4Network(address if type(address) == str else address.decode())
        return IPv4Address(address)

    except (AddressValueError, NetmaskValueError):
        pass
```

2. Create a CIDRField for Django

   class CIDRField(models.GenericIPAddressField):
   def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
   if not prepared:
   value = self.get_prep_value(value)
   return ipaddress.ip_network(value if type(value) == str else value.decode())